# How can i restrict a page to certain user roles?

Tags: content-restriction

I would like to know how can i restrict a certain page to be shown only to specific user roles & also show an error message that the user is not allowed to view this page if the user role is otherwise.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rudimentary (untested) version of the code that I can think will resolve your issue:

```
<?php
/**
 * Redirect UnAuthorized Users from my page.
 * 
 * Users will be redirected to another page if not authorized.
 */
function wpse375662_redirect_unauth_users() {
    // Not that particular page - bail out.
    if ( ! is_page( $page_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // User has permission - bail out.
    if ( current_user_can( $user_role_here ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Add URL parameter.
    $parameterized_url = add_query_arg( $your_custom_page_url, 'unauth', true );

    // Redirect the user.
    wp_redirect( $parameterized_url, 302 );
    exit();
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse375662_redirect_unauth_users' );

/**
 * Display a message upon redirection.
 */
function wpse375662_message_for_unauth_users() {
      if ( filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'unauth', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN ) ) {
            echo '<div style="style="absolute; top: 300px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); z-index: 9999; padding: 2rem;" role="alert">You are not authorized to display the content of that page</div>';
      }
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpse375662_message_for_unauth_users' );
```

There could be other ways to tackle the issue - it could just be one of them.

Comment: How can i add the page ID or URL in this code? I have tried to change the $page_id to $6151 but it turned as syntax error, the same goes with $your_custom_page_url when i tried to place the page URL.

Comment: I'm afraid, you better hire a WordPress developer.